# find with grep not working inside shell script

Tags: shell, unix, grep, find, ksh

I am using the below command to find the file names and it works fine when execute from command line:

```
$AIX->: find . | xargs grep -l "BE00036"
./6281723219129
$AIX->:
```

But the same command is not working when execute from shell script(ksh):

```
$AIX->: ksh test.ksh
**find: bad option -l**
```

part of my code is:

```
Var="find . | xargs grep -l \"BE00036\"
print `$Var`
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assign the output of a command to a variable, you can do

```
Var="$(find . | xargs grep -l \"BE00036\")"
print "$Var"
```

Answer (score 0):

This below one works for me:

```
var=`find . | xargs grep -l 'BE00036'`
echo "$var"
```

Comment: Please: `echo "$var"`.

Comment: And its better to use parentheses `$(code)` compare to back tics `'code'` (not possible to show them here in comment filed, used single quote to represent back tics). See post `pfnuesel`